# StructureMap grouping of named instances

Tags: wcf, validation, structuremap

Long post - sorry....

I'm doing input validation for a WCF service and using StructureMap IoC to instantiate the appropriate validation objects. 
I have 2 different validation groups:

1. Per object validation: means that one input parameter, will be resolve by the Ioc (e.g. `Ioc.ResolveAll<IValidatorObject<InputParameter1>`, .... `<InputParameter2>`... etc). If any rules are found, the validate method is invoked.
2. Per context validation: mean that validation rules are invoked, based on the current context (explicit roles). A context could be 'deposit money' or 'open bank account'. Context validation are usually dependent on 2 or more of the input parameters and is the key difference between object and context validation.

The input validation is performed in the BeforeCall event call in the IParameterInspector (provider/server side!). With this event I get a string containing the operation name (aka. the context) and an object[] with the input parameters.

The problem is that there's multiple validation rules for a single context and the only way I have figured out to register the context in the Ioc, is by using named intances. However I can only register **1** named instance pr. interface. And the interface is not uniquely identifiable by its signature. E.g.

- Context rule for 'create account': `IValidatorContext<User, Account>`
- Context rule for 'deposit money': `IValidatorContext<User, Account>`

So my question is, whether it is possible to register the context in StructureMap in any other way than named instances - or maybe a way to group named instances.

An alternative route, is to implement explicit interfaces for each context, so that the DepositMoney service method might look like this:

```
public Response Deposit(IDepositMoney inputArguements)
```

where IDepositMoney contains the input parameters.

So am I way off here, or can I somehow register a context in StructureMap? Or should I just go ahead and use explicit interface instead (3rd option?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up wrapping each set of input parameters in a context and used the context to register in StructureMap. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of named instances is that the name points to a single instance, so you won't be able to use that feature to do what you are trying to achieve.  I would use explicit interfaces, since this will allow you to auto wire more things and have less calls to your container.

Comment: From what I can read in the API, you can only register one type pr. named instance. The ObjectFactory only has a GetNamedInstance<T>(string namedInstance) : T method. Are you sure you can register multiple named instances and actually resolve them as a collection?

Comment: Oh I completely misunderstood you, sorry about that.  To make sure I understand, you want several different type registered with the same name? That is not possible.

Comment: Yes the idea was some type of grouping based on the context - in my case it would be the method name as a string.